# defining a for loop for operations on each row of a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a data set of length (L) which I named "data".

```
data=raw_data.iloc[:,0]
```

I randomly generated 2000 sample series from "data" and named it "resamples" to have a NumPy matrix of len =2000 and cols=L of the "data".

```
resamples=[np.random.choice(data, size=len(data), replace=True) for i in range (2000)]
```

The code below shows two operations in Scipy.stats using "data" which is a single array. Now I need to perform the same operation on each one of those sample series (2000 rows) by defining a for loop. The challenge is two parameters (loc and scale) are calculated in the first step and they should be used for each row to perform the next one. My knowledge falls short in defining such a for loop. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

```
loc, scale=stats.gumbel_r.fit(data)

return_gumbel=stats.gumbel_r.ppf([0.9999,0.9995,0.999],loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

Comment: Have you considered storing your 2000 series in a dataframe and then leveraging `.apply()` or vectorizing your solution? Performance will be much better than a for loop.

Comment: @rahlf23, are you sure `pandas` `apply` is faster?  Doesn't it just loop through rows of the frame and `apply` the function to each?  `vectorizing` isn't very descriptive in this case.  How would you do that?

Comment: So you have a (2000,L) array, and you want to perform a complex (`stats`) operation on each row (`data` in your code sample?).  Is the calculation for each row independent (not depending previous rows)?

Comment: @hpaulj yes they are independent. The code I have written is working on "data" which is just a single vector. I need to do it  on each one of the generated samples. However, I need them generated in a matrix since I want to find the (std and mean) of each col at the end.

Comment: Now that I'm reading into the details a bit further, I would agree with @hpaulj, I'm not sure of the feasibility of vectorizing this solution considering the steps involved in your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description is a little unclear, but I think you just need:

```
alist = []
for data in resamples:
   loc, scale=stats.gumbel_r.fit(data)
   return_gumbel=stats.gumbel_r.ppf([0.9999,0.9995,0.999],loc=loc, scale=scale)
   alist.append(return_gumbel)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

You could also create `arr` first, and assign `return_gumbel` to the respective rows, but the list append is about the same speed.  The loop could also be written as a list comprehension.

There was talk of `vectorizing`, but given the complex nature of the calculation I doubt if that is feasible - at least not without digging into the details of those `stats` functions.  In `numpy` `vectorizing` means writing a function such that it works with all rows of the array at once, performing the actions in compiled numpy code.